# How to require a selection in my select element on my signup form

Tags: html, validation, select

```
  <label for="select-choice">Birthday:</label>
      <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Month</option>
        <option value="january">Jan</option>
        <option value="february">Feb</option>
        <option value="march">Mar</option>
```

```
<select name="birthday-day" id="day">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
```

```
<select name="birthday-year" id="year">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Year</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
```

The Sign Up or Register page is okay but I could not validate the birthday, When I try filling it on a browser I expect it to demand or require birthday option, every other input option was demanding or requiring me to input an information but if I purposely did not fill the birthday and hit the submit button it will go through just like that, please how do I validate the birthday using HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add "required" to each of your selects and then just add an empty value instead of a "0" value. When you press a button, it will detect it has no value and will automatically make the select required.

```html
<form>
<label for="select-choice">Birthday:</label>
  <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice" required>
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="january">Jan</option>
        <option value="february">Feb</option>
        <option value="march">Mar</option>
  </select>      
  <select name="birthday-day" required>
        <option value="">Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="birthday-year" id="year" required>
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
  </select>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```